# how can i use access pass through query to access sql sp

Tags: ms-access

I have a store procedure has 4 paramater in SQL, and want to bulid a applcation in access to exec this SP.

I have a access form which has four text box just simply type the pass through paramater and one button to click , which has code like these

```
  Private Sub Command13_Click()

  Dim dbs As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim strSQL As String
  Const c_strSQL As String = "EXEC sp_xCopy @CurCo={P1}, @CurNumber={P2}, @NewCo={P3},   @NewNumver={P4}"

 Set dbs = CurrentDb     Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("QueryCopyVendor") 
 strSQL = Replace(c_strSQL, "{P1}", "Forms!CopyVendor!CurCo") 
 strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "{P2}", "Forms!CopyVendor!CurNumber") 
 strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "{P3}", "Forms!CopyVendor!NewCo")
 strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "{P4}", "Forms!CopyVendor!NewNumber")
 qdf.SQL = strSQL
 qdf.Execute
 Set qdf = Nothing
 Set dbs = Nothing

 End Sub
```

but when i submit, i get the fellowing error:

run_time error '3065'
cannot execute a select query

Does that mean i can not have select query in my SP? help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean i can not have select query in my SP?

No, the error message is telling you that Access thinks your query is a SELECT query (or some type of query that returns records) and you are trying to `.Execute` it. Access doesn't like that because it thinks you should be assigning the returned records to a `Recordset`.

To create a pass-through query (PTQ) in DAO you must

- set the `.Connect` property of the QueryDef to at least `ODBC;`, and
- set the `.ReturnsRecords` property to `False` if it does not return a rowset

Here is the bare-bones code to create a PTQ:

```
Sub CreatePTQ()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("ptq")
qdf.Connect = "ODBC;"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.SQL = "EXEC foo"
qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also, in your code you are replacing the placeholders with the *names* of the form controls, e.g., ...

```
strSQL = Replace(c_strSQL, "{P1}", "Forms!CopyVendor!CurCo")
```

...when you should be replacing those placeholders with the controls' *values*...

```
strSQL = Replace(c_strSQL, "{P1}", Forms!CopyVendor!CurCo)
```

...and remember that if any of the parameters are strings then you'll need to put quotes around them in the `EXEC` statement.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it, as you know i am so new to access

Comment: I get the refernce from the following link http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1661807-sql-pass-through-query-combo-box-paramater.html. Would you help me to look at it?

Comment: @user1723572 Have you already created the [QueryCopyVendor] query as a pass-through query (icon in Access looks like a globe), with the appropriate `.Connect` string, and with the `EXEC sp_xCopy ...` command using actual parameters so you can double-click the query in Access and verify that it actually works? Try that first, and then work on executing it from your VBA code.

Comment: yes, i did check before i work on the execute. It works fine.

Comment: @user1723572 I have updated my answer. Also, does the existing [QueryCopyVendor] query in Access have the "globe" icon with the exclamation point (`!`) beside it? (That's the icon for PTQ's with `.ReturnsRecords = False`.)

Comment: I give up. Thank all your help